# Force higher resolution on second monitor on kubuntu

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have an nvidia GTX 260 896 MB and a Monitor Samsung 225 BW that supports 1680x1050 native. And I need to add and apply resolution to nvidia x server settings viewportout to 1920x1080, but it doesn't let me when i click on apply (on blur) it reverts back to 1680x1050. I tried with addmode and newmode commands but the resolution won't come up. On windows 10 it works fine and can keep the monitor on 1920x1080.

OS: Ubuntu KDE 14.04 LTS

[image]

This is what i have in /etc/x11/xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 340.96  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05)  Sun Nov  8 22:50:27 PST 2015

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung S22C300"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 260"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DVI-I-3: 1920x1080 +1920+0 {viewportin=1920x1080}; {viewportout=1920x1080}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {viewportin=1920x1080}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DVI-I-3: 1680x1050 +1680+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {viewportin=1920x1080}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DVI-I-3: 1680x1050_60 +1920+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DVI-I-3: 1680x1050_60 +1920+0 {viewportin=1920x1080}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: It didn't work in this particular case, but others trying to achieve the scaling can try `xrandr --output DP1 --scale 1.14x1.14`

Comment: I got higher resolution multi-monitor setup to work on ubuntu using something like grander --auto --output DVI-I --primary --mode 1920x1080. Can't remember exactly what I did unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I would install ARandR and use that GUI instead of NVIDIA or others. It works fine for me to set and keep resolutions using multiple monitors on Ubuntu flavors of linux.

Open a terminal window and install:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arandr`

Then to start using simply find arandr as an app listed in your applications menu.

After installation, find it in the menu : System -> Preferences -> ARandR

Homepage of ARandR : http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/

Comment: Installed it but don't see how to add a new resolution.

Comment: @user3467855 I have a four monitor setup and it took forever to figure it out. I don't remember and didn't document the steps involved. I had a pain in the ass with Samsung and Dell monitors but finally got them configured and working. Sorry I can provide more that what I already wrote.